# Curious slowdown in opengl when using instanced rendering

Tags: performance, debugging, opengl, graphics

I've run into a quite odd performance issue. So far I've reduced the problem to this: I'm rendering 20x20x20 cubes in a grid, using `glDrawElementsInstanced`, which works fine as long as my camera is far away from the origin, however when it gets closer to the origin, it starts grinding to a halt.

I'm defining my model view projection matrix through:

```
float distance=3.8;
Projection = glm::perspective(65.0f, (float)(width)/height, 0.1f, 300.0f);
View  = glm::lookAt(    glm::vec3(0,0,-distance),
                        glm::vec3(0,0,10),
                        glm::vec3(0,1,0));
Model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.0f, glm::vec3(0.25f, 1.0f,0.75f));
```

With distance at 40, there's no problems, but when distance decreases to about 3.8 and lower, everything grinds to a halt.

The actual call to rendering is carried out through:

```
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(GLvoid*)(0),latticePoints.size());
```

While putting all the vertices in a single buffer and rendering by calling:

```
glBindVertexArray(nonInstancedVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,vertices.size() );
```

Completely removes the behavior. Anyone who's experienced similar behavior who can point me in the direction of a solution? If failing that, anyone who's got an idea of how to track down something like this? I hoped I would be able to determine what was causing the slowdown using gDEBugger, however that just reconfirms that there aren't any other opengl calls, and doesn't really help figuring out what's taking up all the processing time.

Another note is that glDrawArraysInstanced also shows the same slowdown, and that splitting the call into 4 separate calls with a quarter of the geometry each also stops the slowdown.

**Update**

Here's an attempt at a minimal illustration of the problem.

```
//Minimal reproduction of problem

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

//Set to true to use instanced rendering (glDrawElementsInstanced), false to render a generated grid instead (glDrawElements)
    #define Instanced true

//Translation from origin. Problme is pressent at 0 distance, but disapears at ex. 40.
    const float distanceFromOrigin=0;

// Function to load shaders
GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path);


    int main(){

    int     width, height;
    bool    running = true;

    // Initialise GLFW
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES,1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT,GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);

    GLFWwindow* windowRef = glfwCreateWindow( 512, 512, "",0,0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowRef);

    glewInit();

    //Load Shader
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "Simple.vs.c", "Simple.fs.c" );
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    glUseProgram(programID);

    glm::mat4 Model,Projection,MVP,View,checkMVP;

    std::vector<GLuint>  sqIndice = {3,2,1,1,0,3,4,5,6,6,7,4,0,4,7,7,3,0,0,1,5,5,4,0,2,3,7,7,6,2,6,5,1,1,2,6,0,4,7,7,3,0};
    std::vector<GLfloat> sqVertex = {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1};
    std::vector<GLfloat> sqColor = {0.2472,0.24,0.6,0.6,0.24,0.442893,0.6,0.547014,0.24,0.24,0.6,0.33692,0.24,0.353173,0.6,0.6,0.24,0.563266,0.6,0.426641,0.24,0.263452,0.6,0.24};

    const float lattice = 5;
    const int mxn = 10;
    std::vector<GLfloat> v1 = {lattice,-1,0};
    std::vector<GLfloat> v2 = {1,lattice,0};
    std::vector<GLfloat> v3 = {0,0,lattice};
    std::vector<GLfloat> offset = {0,0,-distanceFromOrigin};

    std::vector<GLfloat> latticePoints,sqVertexGrid,sqColorGrid;// = {0,0,0};
    std::vector<GLuint> sqIndiceGrid;
// Looping stuff to generate the full grid of "instances" to render in a single call. 
    int instanceCount=0;
//Generate Lattice vectors, aswell as a vector containing the full grids of indices,vertexes and colors
    for(int x=-mxn;x<mxn;++x){
        for(int y=-mxn;y<mxn;++y){
            for(int z=-mxn;z<mxn;++z){
                for(int n=0;n<3;++n){
                    latticePoints.push_back( x*v1[n]+y*v2[n]+z*v3[n]+offset[n] );
                };
                for(int elm=0;elm<sqVertex.size();elm+=3){
                    for(int n=0;n<3;++n){
                        sqVertexGrid.push_back(sqVertex[elm+n]+x*v1[n]+y*v2[n]+z*v3[n]+offset[n]);
                        sqColorGrid.push_back(sqColor[elm+n]);
                    };
                };
                for(int elm=0;elm<sqIndice.size();++elm){
                    sqIndiceGrid.push_back(sqIndice[elm]+instanceCount*sqVertex.size()/3);
                };
                ++instanceCount;glewInit

            };
        };
    };

#if Instanced==true
//Initialize and fill vertex,color and indice buffers with the relevant data.
GLuint cubeVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//Vertex buffer
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sqVertex.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), &sqVertex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

//Color buffer
    GLuint colorBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sqColor.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), &sqColor[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

// Indice buffer
    GLuint indicesBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indicesBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sqIndice.size()*sizeof(GLuint), &sqIndice[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Lattice point buffer
    GLuint latticePointBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &latticePointBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, latticePointBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, latticePoints.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), &latticePoints[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(2,1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
#elif Instanced==false
GLuint cubeGridVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeGridVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(cubeGridVAO);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//Vertex buffer
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sqVertexGrid.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), &sqVertexGrid[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

//Color buffer
    GLuint colorBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sqColorGrid.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), &sqColorGrid[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

// Indice buffer
    GLuint indicesBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indicesBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sqIndiceGrid.size()*sizeof(GLuint), &sqIndiceGrid[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
#endif


while(running)
{
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(windowRef, &width, &height);
        height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        Projection = glm::perspective(65.0f, (float)(width)/height, 0.1f, 300.0f);
        View  = glm::lookAt(    glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,-(distanceFromOrigin+3.8f)),
                                glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,100.0f),
                                glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
        Model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.0f, glm::vec3(0.25f, 1.0f,0.75f));

        MVP = Projection*View*Model;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE,  glm::value_ptr(MVP));

        #if Instanced==true
            glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
            glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, sqIndice.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(GLvoid*)(0),latticePoints.size());
        #elif Instanced==false
            glBindVertexArray(cubeGridVAO);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sqIndiceGrid.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(GLvoid*)(0));
        #endif

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(windowRef);

        std::cout<<".\n";

    running = !glfwGetKey(windowRef,GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) && !glfwWindowShouldClose(windowRef);
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(windowRef);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
};

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

        // Create the shaders
        GLuint VertexShaderID   = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
        std::string VertexShaderCode;
        std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
        if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
                std::string Line = "";
                while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
                        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
                VertexShaderStream.close();
        }else{
                printf("Impossible to open %s. Are you in the right directory?\n", vertex_file_path);
                return 0;
        }

        // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
        std::string FragmentShaderCode;
        std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
        if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
                std::string Line = "";
                while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
                        FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
                FragmentShaderStream.close();
        }

        GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
        int InfoLogLength;

        // Compile Vertex Shader
        printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
        char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
        glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
        glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

        // Check Vertex Shader
        glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
                std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
                glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
                printf("%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        }

        // Compile Fragment Shader
        printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
        char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
        glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
        glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

        // Check Fragment Shader
        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
                std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
                glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
                printf("%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        }


        // Link the program
        printf("Linking program\n");
        GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
        glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
        glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

        // Check the program
        glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
                std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
                glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
                printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        }

        glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

        return ProgramID;
}
```

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but I just read that instancing is not always a good thing to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11973466/804614. "Instancing shouldn't be used with meshes that have too many vertices or too few. 100-1,000 or so." I can't explain why, but if you're rendering cubes that would be only 8 vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but same thing happens with larger meshes with 540 vertices. And if the issue was due to this, it shouldn't depend on the location of the camera.

Comment: I've tested instancing using 100^3 (1M) cubes on a 580 GTX running at 30-50 fps depending on the the camera position. Tested with random positions and as a compact cube. Didn't notice any slowdowns as described here. Maybe the slowdown is just caused by the amount of overdraw then the cubes cover the entire screen and are drawn from back to front?

Comment: @Grimmy Any idea of how to test if this has something to do with the issue? I would think the overdraw should be identical no matter where you place your camera as long as the relative placements of the geometry is the same.

Comment: Do you really need instancing? If your cubes aren't changing individually, it's better to "bake" them into a single object, instead of using the instancing extension.

Comment: @JariKomppa I appreciate your comment, but the questions isn't about the need for instancing. I'm displaying an issue where instancing causes trouble in the simplest form I can.

Comment: @jVincent If nothing else, dropping instancing would make your test case simpler, and see if the problem is caused by instancing or something else - I really doubt the instancing is the issue (I've implemented instancing in an opengl driver), but who knows..

Comment: @JariKomppa I appreciate your attempts at helping, but did you even look at the code? It has a preprocessor switch for the instancing, and the problem only occurs when using instancing. Suggesting that I just not use instancing is not in any way constructive. I'm not asking for a method of rendering cubes, I'm looking for insight into what I consider extremely odd behavior.

Comment: @jVincent My apologies. Outright, your problem makes no sense whatsoever; the instancing shouldn't have anything to do with projection, and the fact that splitting the drawing to 4 parts solves it suggests there's some kind of strange resource starvation somewhere on the driver or even hardware level.. Have you tried this with different gfx cards? I'm fairly confident the behavior is different from one architecture to another. Also, out of curiosity, which card do you have?

Comment: @JariKomppa, No, I haven't tried it out on other systems, since I don't currently have anything available. I'm using is Intel HD Graphics 4000. If it's a driver or hardware issue, do you have any idea of how to determine this or get more info on the issue?

Comment: @jVincent I suppose the best bet would be to publish the code in a high-profile AAA game, and hope the manufacturer cares enough to release a driver that doesn't have the issue =) If you can get the same behavior from different graphics cards, then it's more likely an issue in your code or algorithm. This one doesn't look that way, though. Drivers and graphics hardware in general are very complex beasts and there's always bound to be some edge cases that show strange behavior.

Comment: @JariKomppa, I'm not asking how to solve the issue if it happens to be a driver or hardware issue, I'm asking how to determine if it's a driver or hardware issue.

Comment: @jVincent Try on different driver versions and different hardware. If your code is coded to a standard, and it only shows odd behavior on one platform, the platform is at fault. Usually =)

Comment: @JariKomppa That doesn't really tell you anything about the issue though. It's just a blackbox "turning it on and off again" solution. I'll repeat myself once again, I'm not just trying to render boxes specifically on my machine. I'm trying to determine what is causing this odd behavior.

Comment: @jVincent I have a radeon based setup and can test the software for you if you like tonight once home, I can sign an NDA or whatever needed if that is an issue, so that you can test it on a different GPU platform, if on the otherhand you have an ATI rig already, probably not that much use for testing purposes.
I too have had this issue: instanced 100k MD2 models and fried my GPU (burned through the board) and never got to the bottom of the slow-down, so if you can use my help, I would be glad to.

Comment: Can You try with 4-element vertex arrays (instead of 3)? Can You show used shaders?

Comment: Would you post your vertex and fragment shaders please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, take a deep breath and take a seat: your problem is graphic card memory speed.

But you could make it easier for the GPU by fixing this bug:

```
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, sqIndice.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(GLvoid*)(0),latticePoints.size());
```

`glDrawElementsInstanced` expects the number of instances to draw as the last parameter. But you pass the number of elements in `latticePoints`. That's 3 times the number of instances. This results in a zero lettice point inside the shader (because of prevented out of bounds access). So 16000 cubes are not translated and are painted at the same position. This results in painting the front face of the cubes 16000 times. The depth buffer doesn't prevent this because the faces do not conceal each other, they are on the same spot.

So when your `distanceFromOrigin` decreases the 16000 center cubes get bigger and bigger. OpenGL has to draw more and more pixels. A lot more, to be exact. It has to draw so much that it hits the speed limit of the graphic card memory.

Read [Diagnose OpenGl Performance Problems](https://ewirch.github.io/2014/01/diagnose-opengl-performance-problems.html) for the whole story.

Comment: Hey, I haven't had much time to look through this old code, so sorry for the slowness on my part in accepting and responding. When encountering the problem and not getting any immediate aid, I did as I suppose many others would and simply continued onwards working around the problem. But the bigger question here of cause wasn't just how to get this specific code correct, but how one goes about debugging unknown issues, and your blog post was positively awesome example of that. So thank you for the great answer.